# SQL Server Dark Theme -- Drop down menu too dark, how do I change it?

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2017

I have enabled the 'Dark Theme' on SQL Server 2017. It is all great, but when I right click in my Object Explorer on a task or something, it is too dark to read. Does anyone know how to change this? See screenshot for what I mean.

I've gone through tools -> environment -> fonts and colors and tried to find where these settings would be, but I'm sure what this element is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSMS Dark Theme is still technically under development and not complete, to enable it you have to do a workaround in the first place modifying text files and uncommenting out some value (I forget the exact file). This is the best you get, unfortunately.